# ios - Passing on values from a UIPickerView when it is subclassed

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, uipickerview, subclass

I am sorry since this has asked before, but I just can't get my head wrapped around it.

I have a UIPickerView that works all fine and I add it to my UIViewController with

```
    _pv = [[CategoryPicker alloc] init];
    _textField.inputView = _pv;
```

_pv is the UIPickerView and _textField is the textField where I want the results to appear in.

So I when I use this line of code:

```
_pv.categoryPicker.delegate = self; //set in my viewDidLoad
```

and this is then placed in the UIViewController:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection

_textField.text = [_pv.categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

I am able to populate the the TextField, but the UIPickerView is filled with a "?" for every entry of the array.

Now when I do this:

```
_pv.categoryPicker.delegate = _pv.self; //set in my viewDidLoad
```

and I put this in the UIPickerView:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
// Handle the selection

_outputArray = [_categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"The item selected = %@", _outputArray);


 }
```

The UIPickerView is populated, but the data is not passed on to the TextField.

So this is where I am stuck - I need to have the results in both places.
Now I thought I do that with subClassing, but everything I have read on that does not work for me.

Please help me:-)

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the full documentation for the [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) protocol.

Basically, what you want to do is set your UIViewController as the delegate of the UIPickerView like so:

```
_pv.categoryPicker.delegate = self;
```

And then in your UIViewController you want to implement the following UIPickerViewDelegate methods:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // called when a row is selected
    _textField.text = [_pv.categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // here is where you populate the contents of the pickerView
    // return the title that you want to appear in 'row'
     return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", row];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have something similar to that know - I was thinking that I didn't have to write any code in the UIViewController, but it seems that I can't get away with that.

Comment: Well, if you want your UIPickerView to be a delegate of itself (which is a pretty odd design) -- then you need it to have a reference to the UIViewController's textField, and then in the 'didSelectRow' delegate method you just have to set the textField's text like how you would in the UIViewController. But my opinion is you should use the method I show above and make your UIViewController be the delegate.

Comment: Alright I'll look into that and see if I can refine my code a bit:-)

Comment: Cool - I had a play and your answer worked, but I guess you knew that already:-) Congrats on your bounty:-) I can give it to you in 16 hours - SO gives me a warning, so you should see it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar very recently. I have a UIPickerView that loads values from an array and when a row inside the UIPicker is selected, it updates the value inside a cell in a UITableView. But you can update the value inside a text field easily too:

Inside the header file:

In your header file, add:

```
// You will not need to set the view as the delegate again.

@interface yourClass: UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    UIPickerView *_pv;
    UITextField *_textField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *_pv;
```

Inside your implementation:

```
@synthesize _pv;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark View Lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Initialize the array
        _categoryArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"1", @"2", @"3",
                        @"4", @"5", nil];

        // Initialize text field of type UITextField and set its input type as picker viewer
        _textField.inputView = pickerViewer; 
     }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   // The array with all the values that you want to see inside the picker viewer
   return [_categoryArray count]; 
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   // Value inside the picker viewer will be loaded for the output array
   return [_categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];
} 

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // When a value is selected in picker viewer, take its value and assign it to the text view
    //NSLog(@"Picker view row selected");
    _textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_categoryArray objectAtIndex:row]]; 
}
```

Also drag a picker viewer on your view in the IB, and connect it to _pv inside the file owner, because it is an IBOutlet.

Hope it helps. I implemented mine inside a UITablewViewController and had multiple UIPickerViewers inside the same view. So I edited out some code, if I missed something and it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Your answer does not look at my question - I am implementing it over 2 different files. so i have one UIViewController and one UIPickerView, but at no point in your answer do you import the one into the other??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but in order to populate the `UIPickerView` you need to do something like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{  
    return [_categoryArray objectAtIndex:row];   
}
```